# How to pivot a list/collection with key value pair values using LINQ and a dynamic list of keys to use?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of accounts with label (key) value attributes like this:

[image]

and I would like to pivot the labels so they become column headers and showing their values to look like this and have one row per account:

[image]

Using this LINQ statement works when I know the labels to display in advance:

```
accounts.GroupBy(a => a.AccountId).
                    Select( g => new {
                        AccountID = g.Key,
                        FirstName = g.Where(c=>c.Label == "First Name").Select(s=>s.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        LastName = g.Where(c=>c.Label == "Last Name").Select(s=>s.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                    });
```

Now the requirements have changed so that the labels to display are known only during run time. The LINQ needs to be generic enough to be able to use any number of labels. Number of labels in the list will usually be fewer than what's in the database. My example is just using 2 of them. Not all accounts have entries (or values) of each for each label, meaning the label and value rows could be missing for some accounts or the value could be null if the label exists.

So I created a list of labels:

```
List<string> listOfLabelsToDisplay = new List<string> {"First Name","Last Name"};
```

and I am trying to craft a LINQ statement and I am having a mental block. Also trying to know what to do about the property names which depend of the label value.

Any ideas?

My attempt obviously is wrong but trying to show what I am trying to accomplish :

```
accounts.GroupBy(a => a.AccountId).
                        Select( g => new {
                            AccountID = g.Key,
                            Enumerable.Range(0,listOfLabelsToDisplay.Count-1).Select((listIndex)) =>
                            {
                                genericname? = g.Where(c=>c.Label == listOfLabelsToDisplay[listIndex]).Select(s=>s.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: If you don't know the labels, how do you even know which order to place them in?  one user would have first name first, and last name second and another user could have last name first and first name second

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. "First Name" is the first label in the list as shown, "Last Name" is the second...etc. That's the order. The where clause picks the corresponding value for each label. The order of label/value pairs in the database is immaterial. If this is not what you mean, please provide an example of your assumption.

Comment: First Name may be first in the list, but there is no guarantee that the database will always return it as such unless you specify it in an order by statement.  But, since your requirement is to allow arbitrary labels with nothing hard coded or pre-defined, that means you can't specify the order, thus items can appear in whatever order the database wants to present them which may not be the order you expect.

Comment: I am using a where clause by label name so it doesn't matter in what order the rows come in. There are no ordinal positions used. I am using each string from the label list to look up the value. For example the first label is "First Name". Go to the collection and get me the 'value' value from the row whose label is "First Name". So it's kinda hard coded. Just like in SQL: Select value from tablename where label = "First Name". Here, instead of me hard coding "First Name" in the lambda like in the first example, I am just getting it from the list of labels. One label at a time in the loop..

Comment: .. starting from label #0 to the last label. "First Name" is the first label in the label list but it does not mean it has to be the first one in the group collection for each account. It can be in any row. The 'where' takes care of this.